# Return a tf.Variable from an Estimator

Tags: tensorflow

I have an Tensorflow Estimator defined by a model function in the usual way. 
I want to determine which of my (zscore normalised) inputs are significant to the result, and which can be eliminated.   I have altered the model to introduce two changes:

(1) A new layer `weight_layer` which is randomly intialized and elementwise multiplied with `input_layer`.

```
weight_layer   =  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, inputs_n], 0.5, 1))
weighted_input = tf.multiply(weight_layer, input_layer)
first_hidden_layer =  tf.layers.dense(weighted_input,  
                                      int(inputs_n), 
                                      activation=tf.nn.relu, 
                                      name='dense1')
```

(2) A penalty `sparsity` which is added to the loss function to penalize the loss by the sum of the weights in `weight_layer`

```
 sparsity = tf.reduce_sum(weight_layer)    
 loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions) + (1000*sparsity)
```

The trouble comes at prediction time, when I try to return the values of `weight_layer`, as follows:

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
   return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec( mode=mode, 
                                      predictions={
                                       "predictions": predictions, 
                                       "sparsity" : weight_layer})
```

I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: predictions[sparsity] must be Tensor, 
 given: <tf.Variable 'Model/Variable:0' shape=(1, 275) dtype=float32_ref>
```

This seems odd, since although predictions[sparsity] is not a Tensor, it is a tf.Variable, and the tf.Variable documentation suggests I can treat a tf.Variable 'like a normal tf.Tensor'.

How can I fix the above to return the weight_layer, or if I there is a more fundamental mistake, please recommend a way for me to determine which of my input variables are significant.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I don't know very well the dynamics of `EstimatorSpec`, it seems you are trying to feed the model the `weight_layer` into `sparsity` Variable, but as they have different shapes due to `tf.reduce_sum`, hence it's raising the error.